# Displaying image from SQL Server database

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing

I am storing images in a SQL Server database as byte arrays and using a handler to display the image on the web page. Images comes properly on Internet explorer but it some as strange characters in chrome and firefox.

Like

```
 ÿØÿáExifII*ÿìDuckyPÿáohttp://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/ ÿíHPhotoshop 3.08BIMZ%G8BIM%üá‰È·Éx/4b4XwëÿîAdobedÀÿÛ
```

My code for handler is

```
if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
{
   // context.Response.Write(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
   string dbcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;

   SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbcon);
   con.Open();

   SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Offers_bigimage from Offers where Offers_OfferId=@empid", con);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", context.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());

   SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
   dr.Read();
   context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Offers_bigimage"]);
   dr.Close();
   con.Close();
}
else
{
   context.Response.Write("No Image Found");
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the content type for the image.  You can look up a list of mime types depending on the type of image you're using, below is an example for a jpg.  Notice the line:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
```

**Full Example**

```
if (context.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
{
    // context.Response.Write(context.Request.QueryString["id"]);
    string dbcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CS1"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(dbcon);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Offers_bigimage from Offers where Offers_OfferId=@empid", con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", context.Request.QueryString["id"].ToString());
    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    dr.Read();

    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
    context.Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])dr["Offers_bigimage"]);
    dr.Close();
    con.Close();
}
else
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("No Image Found");
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot Worked  for me.. One more question i have do you think the above code can be exploited for sql injection or blind sql injection

Comment: No it's not because you're using parameterized queries. However one problem is that you're not properly handling the Request.QueryString, for example if it's supposed to be an integer you should check to make sure what was submitted is an integer before moving forward.

Comment: Can you please tel me how to compile a .net website with debug symbols and what actually is the purpose of using debug symbols